# Can't open output file: permission denied

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, permission-denied

I am running CodeBlocks on a Windows 10 machine. Since this morning, I cannot build a specific project because the permission to open the output .exe file is denied. Said task was at first unwilling to be closed through Task Manager, and after restarting CodeBlocks it just does not show up and the issue persists.

When I tried deleting the file, I got another denial as "the file is open in System". Disabling antivirus software did not work. Any insights?

Comment: AFAIK this happens on windows when the executable is still running. Check in Taskmanager.

Comment: _"Said task was at first unwilling to be closed through Task Manager"_ How did you manage that?

Comment: @PreferenceBean I have no idea, what I mean is that the CodeBlocks console was showing in Task Manager, but the End Task would not do a thing. No error message or freezing, more like a dead button.

Comment: @Axel well now the executable is not running or showing in Task Manager, it looks like a file lock preventing edition/deletion of the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does rebooting the computer help at all? :-)
Should resolve any file locks. Don't go to hibernate and back, but actually reboot. Or at least log off and then log in again.

Edit: came to think of [Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default). It might help you find where locks are from.

Comment: As usual, rebooting Windows is a magical fix for obscure problems... No problems rebuilding after restart indeed, but I still wonder if there is a less violent way to get rid of the file lock.